# JavaScript doesn't update form select with option

Tags: javascript, quirks-mode

I have a small problem, I have 4 separate drop downs, I want to add an option to the drop down using javascript, on my working code (php constructs the dropdowns initially with value from MySQL) question_type and question_subtype work, however option_type option_subtype do not.

Since a question could have multiple options, I'm using quirksmode (http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/domform.html) to add new dropdowns--which is probably the problem.

jsfiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/aeqsdzpk/2/

There are no errors when I look at the console.

Two are working just fine,

```
<select name="question_type" id="question_type">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2  </option> 
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>

<select name="question_subtype" id="question_subtype">
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B  </option> 
  <option value="C">C</option>
  <option value="D">D</option>
</select>

<select name="option_type[]" id="option_type">
  <option value="opt-1">opt1</option>
  <option value="opt-2">opt2  </option> 
  <option value="opt-3">opt3</option>
  <option value="opt-4">opt4</option>
</select>

<select name="option_subtype[]" id="option_subtype">
  <option value="optA">optA</option>
  <option value="optB">optB  </option> 
  <option value="optC">optC</option>
  <option value="optD">optD</option>
</select>
```

The Javascript I'm using is here:

```
 function addOption()
  {
   var opt = document.getElementById('options').value,
   new_option  = document.getElementById('new_option').value,
   option = document.createElement("option"),
   x = document.getElementById(opt);
   alert(opt);
  option.text = new_option;
   x.add(option);
  document.getElementById('options').style.display='none';
 document.getElementById('new_option').value='';
 }
```

Here is the full code in case jsfiddle is not accessible

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<!-- saved from url=(0042)http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/domform.html -->
<html lang="en"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<title>Sandbox Question Addition Form</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.quirksmode.org/quirksmode.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.quirksmode.org/quirksmode.js"></script>
<style>body {padding-top: 161px;}</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
 <!--
 var counter = 0;
 function init() {
 document.getElementById('moreFields').onclick = moreFields;
 moreFields();
 }
function moreFields() {
counter++;
var newFields = document.getElementById('readroot').cloneNode(true);
newFields.id = '';
newFields.style.display = 'block';
var newField = newFields.childNodes;
for (var i=0;i<newField.length;i++) {
    var theName = newField[i].name
    if (theName)
        newField[i].name = theName + counter;
}
var insertHere = document.getElementById('writeroot');
insertHere.parentNode.insertBefore(newFields,insertHere);
//document.getElementById("moreFields").focus();
}

// -->
</script>
<style>
.button {
background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
border: none;
color: white;
padding: 4px 8px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 16px;
margin: 4px 2px;
-webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
transition-duration: 0.4s;
cursor: pointer;
}
.button1 {
 background-color: white;
color: black;
border: 2px solid #4CAF50;
}
.button1:hover {
background-color: #4CAF50;
color: white;
  }
.button2 {
background-color: white;
color: black;
border: 2px solid #008CBA;
}
.button2:hover {
background-color: #008CBA;
color: white;
}
.button3 {
background-color: white;
color: black;
border: 2px solid #f44336;
}
.button3:hover {
background-color: #f44336;
color: white;
}
.button4 {
background-color: white;
color: black;
border: 2px solid #e7e7e7;
}
.button4:hover {background-color: #e7e7e7;}
.button5 {
 background-color: white;
color: black;
border: 2px solid #555555;
}
.button5:hover {
background-color: #555555;
color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="readroot" style="display: none !important"><p>
<input class="button button3" type="button" value="Remove Option" onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);"><br><br>
<label> Option Type</label><br>
 <select name = option_type[] id = option_type><option value = VIP>VIP
 </option>
 <option value = All>All </option>
 <option value = Boost>Boost </option>
 <option value = Sales>Sales </option>
 </select><br>
 <label>    Option Subtype</label><br>
 <select name = option_subtype[] id = option_subtype><option value = Time Item>Time Item </option>
 <option value = All>All </option>
 <option value = Upkeep>Upkeep </option>
 <option value = Titles>Titles </option>
  <option value = Missing Item (Google)>Missing Item (Google) </option>
 <option value = Missing Prizes (Research)>Missing Prizes (Research)    </option>
 </select><br>  
 <label>Option Suggestion</label>
 <textarea cols = '100' name = 'option_suggestion[]'  placeholder = "Suggested Response" ></textarea>
  </div>
  <div>
 <form method="post" action="add_option.php">
<label> Question Type</label><br>
<select name = question_type id = question_type><option value = All>All </option>
<option value = VIP  >VIP   </option>
<option value = Sales>Sales </option>
<option value = Challenges>Challenges </option>
<option value = Account>Account </option>
</select><br>
<label> Question Subtype</label><br>
 <select name = question_subtype id = question_subtype><option value = > </option>
    <option value = Time Item>Time Item </option>
   <option value = Missing Item (Google)>Missing Item (Google) </option>
  </select><br>
  <textarea cols = '100' name = 'question'  placeholder="Enter Question here" ></textarea>
 <span id="writeroot"></span>
  <br>
  <input class="button button1" type="button" id="moreFields" value="New Option"><br>
  <input type="submit" class="button button2" value="Send form">

 </form>
 <h3>Add New Question or Option Type </option>
  <script>
  function showOptions()
  {
      document.getElementById('options').style.display='block';
 }
  function addOption()
 {
var opt = document.getElementById('options').value,  
new_option  = document.getElementById('new_option').value,
option = document.createElement("option"),
x = document.getElementById(opt);
alert(opt);
option.text = new_option;
x.add(option);
document.getElementById('options').style.display='none';
document.getElementById('new_option').value='';
}
 </script>
 <input type = 'text' id = 'new_option' onchange = 'showOptions()'>
 <select name = 'dropdown' id ='options' style = 'display:none' onchange = 'addOption()'>
 <option selected disabled value = ''>Add to... </option>
 <option value = 'question_type'>Question Type </option>
 <option    value = 'question_subtype'>Question Sub Type </option>
  <option   value = 'option_type'>Option Type </option>
  <option   value = 'option_subtype'>Option Sub Type </option>
 </select>
```

Comment: your code looks incomplete. i dont see any `#options` or where `addOption` is called.

Comment: @DanielA.White the full code is in the jsfiddle

Comment: the full code *should* be posted here for a [mcve]

Comment: I copied the source from my page here: https://jsfiddle.net/itsjustcarlos/n6z41bev/   the New Option copies the option_type and option_subtype fields - My thought is that because the id is duplicated when I copy it, is the reason it doesnt work.

Comment: What's the question here? What do you mean by "using quirksmode"? The jsfiddle you link to appears to be working fine for me with Chrome on Windows 8.1... But please do copy *all* of the code to this question on Stack Overflow; many people can't access jsfiddle due to businesses filtering them out.

Comment: Hey Mike, Added the code, plus a link to quirksmode.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, you need to step away and rethink thing and see it in a different format, remembered about getElementsByClassName.

```
 function addOption()
 {
var opt = document.getElementById('options').value,
new_option  = document.getElementById('new_option').value,
option = document.createElement("option"),
x = document.getElementsByClassName(opt);
console.log(x);
option.text = new_option;
var arrayLength = x.length;
for(c=0;c<arrayLength;c++)
 {
    x[c].add(option);

  }
 // x.add(option);
document.getElementById('options').style.display='none';
 document.getElementById('new_option').value='';
}
```